# How to change debug/release options for all projects in my solution at once?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a visual studio solution that has many projects.

Is it possible to change the build to debug or release globally for all projects?

Having to change them individually is a real pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you open the Configuration dropdown, the last option says "Configuration Manager" (you also access it with BUILD -> Configuration Manager)

[[image: Configuration dropdown][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXFnM.png)

In there you can select Solution configuration

[image: Configuration manager]

This changes it for all projects

Comment: I'll add... this dropdown is on the "Standard" toolbar. You may also right click the Solution Explorer to access "Configuration Manager".

Comment: I can't believe I missed this...somehow I drew a blank for a span of 15 minutes!